# PhpStorm files(images) not automatically added to commit

Tags: javascript, php, html, web, phpstorm

Just started using PhpStorm but have one major issue which is that it does not seem to pick up on images that have been added outside of the editor into one of the project folders. I have to refresh the folder the image was added to, then right click, subversion and "add" so that it is included in the next commit. Is there no option to just say, find all new files and add them?

I've come from using Eclipse where a refresh automatically flagged any new files to be included in the next commit. I'm assuming there is a way to configure this but I have no idea how.

Ideally I'd just like to refresh the top level folder that would then flag and add any new files, does anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: What version of PHPStorm are you using?

Comment: Have you tried `File | Synchronize` before committing to VCS?

Comment: I'm using PhpStorm 7.0 - and yes tried synchronise but it does not seem to be much apart from sometimes refresh the view. Files are not added ready to commit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see all unversioned files in the changes view (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>9</kbd> or View -> Tool Windows -> Changes). From there you can easily add them to Subversion (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> or Right-Click -> Add to VCS)